# Volvo S80 II 2.4 D5 DPF (Diesel Particulate Filter) regeneration conditions

Tags: exhaust, diesel, volvo, s80, diesel-particulate-filter

What are the conditions required for the DPF (Diesel Particulate Filter) regeneration?

Is it only exhaust temperature or speed and RPM also?

I'm wondering if DPF can regenerate while car is at standstill keeping the revs high in a neutral gear?

Answer (score 1):

**It has to get HOT.**

As you seem to know and elude to by asking if sitting and idling at a higher RPM could resolve the issue.

If the car is fit can you just drive it in a lower gear at a higher RPM?  Not savagly high like a teenager but reasonably high.  If you would be in 5th on the freeway can you drive it in 4th?

Some DPF's can get seriously clogged up with lots of short drives and not a lot of long running.  I recently drove a friends on the freeway with him for about 30 minutes in a lower gear and upon our return his idling issue completely went away.